# Bootstrap - Modal - Access value of parent object

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a class of links which when clicked launch a modal window. Within the modal window how can I access the href of the object which spawned the modal? My goal is to use a button within the modal window which, when clicked will open a window to the href of the caller.

I don't need code to display the modal window for this class of links, just how to acccess values from the parent object.

thanks

Example as requested:

```
<li><a href="http://foo" rel="ExtLink">blah</a></li>
<li><a href="http://bar" rel="ExtLink">Test</a></li>
```

Modal:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="ModalTest" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalTestLabel" aria-hidden="true">

          <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="ModalTestLabel">External URL warning</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                        External URL warning here.
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Exit</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">I understand, visit link</button>
                  </div>
                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
          </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Open from JS:

```
$("a[rel='ExtLink']").click(function(e){
    $('ModalTest').show();

});
```

So if I click either of these a modal window opens. Within the modal window I want a button that when pressed launches the href of the caller. Thanks

Comment: Do you have specific ID's on these links, can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: @MehmetSeçkin example added as requested. Thanks

Comment: One approach - You could have a hidden item on your page that stores the url of the link used to trigger the modal. Just set this item whenever you call your modal. Give it a unique ID so you can retrieve the value (and set it) easily with jQuery.

Comment: Could you provide HTML for the modal itself?

Comment: @Drumbeg added example

Comment: How do you open the dialog? Is there some Javascript code? Do you open the dialog from multiple links?

Comment: @OlafDietsche JS example added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(document).on("click", "ul li a", function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();
     var link = $(this).attr('href');
     $("#myModal a").attr('href',link);
     $(".moadl").modal("show");
});
```

**html**

```
<ul>
<li><a href="http://foo" rel="ExtLink">blah</a></li>
<li><a href="http://bar" rel="ExtLink">Test</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="modal hide" id="myModal">
 <div class="modal-header">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <a href="">go to link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rt8Ya/)