# How set a value in modal action url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

when click in delete button the modal delete button link have a value from delete button.
my code

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", "#myModal", function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var _self = $(this);

    var myBookId = _self.data('adid');
    $("adid").val(myBookId);

    $(_self.attr('href')).modal('show');
});



</script>
```

delete button code

```
print'<td><button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" id="myModal" data-target="#myModal" data-adid='.$cd[$i][0].'>Delete Item</a></button>
```

modal code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Heads Up!
                     <p>What you are doing will delete a data!</p></h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><a href="a=yes&adid=" >Delete</a></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

when click in delete item  button then show a modal and this modal delete link have a url like `?a=yes&adid=`

after `&adid` have a value that come fro delete item data-adid.

but my code not work

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381482/bootstrap-modal-access-value-of-parent-object/21382155#21382155

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have the same id(myModal) for delete-button as well as for modal.
Try below code

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" id="deleteBtn" data-target="#myModal" data-adid='.$cd[$i][0].'>Delete Item</button>

<div class="modal hide" id="myModal"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Heads Up!
                         <p>What you are doing will delete a data!</p></h4>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><a href="" >adid=''</a></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

script

```
$(document).on("click", "#deleteBtn", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var link = $(this).attr('data-adid');        
    $("#myModal .btn-success a").attr('href',link);
    $(".modal").modal("show");
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rt8Ya/1/)

Comment: i use your code but not add any value in a=yes&adid=